# Match file names containing a given list of substrings

Tags: python

I'm writing a module that will take in an array of strings among other command line arguments. The array would be something like:

`['PUPSFF', 'PCASPE', 'PCASEN']`

My module has a method that will search for files matching a possible format in a directory:

```
def search(self, fundCode, type):
    funds_string = '_'.join(fundCode)
    files = set(os.listdir(self.unmappedDir))
    file_match = 'citco_unmapped_{type}_{funds}_{start}_{end}.csv'.format(type=type, funds=funds_string, start=self.startDate, end=self.endDate)
    if file_match in files:
        filename = os.path.join(self.unmappedDir, file_match)
        return self.read_file(filename)
    else:
        Logger.error('No {type} file/s found for {funds}, between {start} and {end}'.format(type=type, funds=fundCode, start=self.startDate, end=self.endDate))
```

So if my directory has a file like this one:

`citco_unmapped_positions_PUPSFF_PCASPE_PCASEN_2018-07-01_2018-07-11.csv`

And I pass this array as the cmd line argument: `['PUPSFF', 'PCASPE', 'PCASEN']`

After calling my method (and passing in the rest of the `self` arguments) like this:

`positions = alerter.search(alerter.fundCodes, 'positions')`

It will search, find that file, and do whatever in needs to do.

**However**, I want it to be independent of the order. so that it will still find the file if the command line arguments are written like this:

`['PCASPE', 'PCASEN', 'PUPSFF']` or
`['PCASEN', 'PUPSFF', 'PCASPE']` or whatever

Any ideas on how to go on about this?

Comment: You could try using the `glob` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `all` function to see the each of the needed tags is in the file name.  This example should get you going:

```
files = [
    "citco_unmapped_positions_PUPSFF_PCASPE_PCASEN_2018-07-01_2018-07-11.csv",   # yes
    "citco_unmapped_positions_PUPSFF_NO_WAY_PCASEN_2018-07-01_2018-07-11.csv",   # no
    "citco_unmapped_positions_PCASEN_PCASEN_PUPSFF_2018-07-01_2018-07-11.csv",   # no
    "citco_unmapped_positions_PCASPE_PCASEN_PUPSFF_2018-07-01_2018-07-11.csv",   # yes
]

tags = ['PUPSFF', 'PCASPE', 'PCASEN']
for fname in files:
    if (all(tag in fname for tag in tags)):
        # the file is a match.
        print("Match", fname)
```

Output:

```
Match citco_unmapped_positions_PUPSFF_PCASPE_PCASEN_2018-07-01_2018-07-11.csv
Match citco_unmapped_positions_PCASPE_PCASEN_PUPSFF_2018-07-01_2018-07-11.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a possible solution with `permutations from itertools`

```
def search(self, fundCodes, type):
    permutations = self.find_permutations(fundCodes)

    files = set(os.listdir(self.unmappedDir))
    for perm in permutations:
        fund_codes = '_'.join(perm)
        file_match = 'citco_unmapped_{type}_{funds}_{start}_{end}.csv'.format(type=type, funds=fund_codes, start=self.startDate, end=self.endDate)
        if file_match in files:
            filename = os.path.join(self.unmappedDir, file_match)
            return self.read_file(filename)
        else:
            Logger.error('No {type} file/s found for {funds}, between {start} and {end}'.format(type=type, funds=fund_codes, start=self.startDate, end=self.endDate))

def find_permutations(self, list):
    perms = [p for p in permutations(list)]
    return perms
```

Probably really slow though.